Is it mandatory to have power bi installed to view reports
I have a Question wrt Power BI.
If a business person or end user just wants to view the dashboard and charts in power Bi on a daily basis should they install power BI on there laptop?
Please let me know as I'm new to power bi and trying to implement power bi dashboards at work place which will be used by non technical business people.

No; anyone can access reports using a web-browser connected to either Microsoft 365 or an on-prem PowerBI Report Server. You don't typically install the Report Server on end-users' machines.

Thanks for responding. If they access from web browser will the graphs and reports be interactive? Also can you please let me know how to login to power bi web, is there any generic web link?

By visiting this site you can see your report. Anyone with your powerbi credentials can see the report. Also if you want to embed the report in your personal website can do this by using embedded token.

Thanks for letting me know. Will check this.
